# Jquery Slideshow Suggestion

Tags: slider, slideshow

Any suggestion where can I find a jquery plugin with these criteria:

- From the thumbnail image pops a gallery/slideshow of image
- The gallery will have next/previous button, auto-play button, caption, and numbered image marker.

I found good plugins that has some but not all. They don't fully satisfy my needs.

I hope you can help me find one.

Thanks

Comment: get one of the plugin which answer all your requirements and write the remaining yourself?

Comment: Try [LightBox](http://lokeshdhakar.com/projects/lightbox/).

Answer (score 2):

I don't understand exactly what you're talking about but you can try jquery lightbox. Might meet your needs. I personally love fancy box --> (http://fancybox.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Try jQuery fancybox. Makes life easy